# How to batch combine PDFs with sub-folder based non-JavaScript bookmarks

Tags: vbscript, pdf-generation, bookmarks, subdirectory

Having been an avid reader here for many years, I finally have a question of my own that I couldn't find an answer for.

I am looking for a solution, preferably VB scriptable, that combines several PDF files from different subfolders into one new PDF and adds bookmarks based on the folder structure, i.e. the first page originating from the first file from a certain folder gets a first level bookmark based on the folder name, and then a second level bookmark based on the file name. All subsequent files from that folder get second level bookmarks linked under the first level bookmark.

As an added complication, the bookmarks must point to the location in the document; they must not be JavaScript based and call actions.

This should all be happening on a Win7 PC.

Unfortunately I don't know much about how the internal workings of PDFs (yet), but I can't quite believe that that problem was so uncommon that it isn't solved already!?

Can anyone help by pointing me in the right direction (or providing script, of course, if it's that easy), or by confirming that the above isn't possible, or with anything else, really?

Thank you very much!
All the best